# Python / R Verificar picos de densidade no ggplot2

Tags: python, r, ggplot2

Tenho dois conjuntos de dados formados da seguinte maneira:

A= {id1: 0.3, id2: 0.1, id3: 0.3 ... idn: 0.2}

B= {id1: 0.01, id2: 0.04, id3: 0.75 ... idn: 0.9}

Utilizei a função `ggplot` do R para plotar os valores de densidades no mesmo gráfico, ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber quais sãos os id's que estão nos picos de cada densidade. Por exemplo, quais são os id's que estão no pico (em vermelho) de cada densidade?  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber se os id's são diferentes ou iguais nos picos, ou seja, nos valores de alta densidade.

Comment: Que linguagem: Python ou R?

Comment: Estou usando R, mas a solução de como fazer isso pode ser em R ou Python.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode pegar os dados do gráfico gerado pelo `ggplot2` ao pedir o `print` explicitamente.

Por exemplo, vamos gerar um histograma:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10000))
grafico <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) + geom_density()
grafico
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para pegar os dados do gráfico e assim saber qual o valor máximo peça o print explicitamente, salve os dados e veja o valor máximo da densidade:

```
dados_grafico <- print(grafico)$data[[1]]
dados_grafico[which.max(dados_grafico$density), c("x","density")]
             x   density
238 -0.1253751 0.3963933
```

Neste caso o máximo ocorre em x = -0.1253751 com densidade de 0.3963933.

Comment: Muito bom Carlos! A partir disso, como eu encontraria os id's? No caso, quem é  id com densidade 0.3963933? Nesse seu conjunto de dados, não tem os id's para cada valor, mas considerando o meu, como funcionaria isso?

Comment: @Fillipe  a densidade não vai ser de um id específico ainda mais com dados contínuos. O máximo que você pode ver são os id's que estão próximos de x = -0.1253, por exemplo.

Comment: Hmmm entendi! Como eu faço p ver os id's que estão próximos de x = -0.1253?  Se eu fizer o histograma (sem densidade) eu consigo achar exatamente os valores de picos e seus id's, já que não são contínuos?

Comment: @Fillipe você pode pegar no data.frame os id's estão próximos de x = -0.1253 por uma pequena diferença. É mais ou menos a mesma ideia do histograma, para fazer o histograma você tem que definir intervalos da variável para calcular as frequências.

Comment: acha que se eu pegasse a frequência de cada valor e pegasse os que tem maiores frequência, daria a certo também ?

Comment: @Fillipe se os seus dados não forem contínuos, sim, mas é como se você estivesse fazendo um histograma na menor granularidade possível.

Comment: Meus dados são discretos. Acho que fazendo isso (com o histograma) o resultado seja mais concreto, no sentido que, pegarei os mais altos (frequentes). Não acha?

Comment: Pegarei a frequência de todos. Pegarei a frequência do maior, tirarei 20% do valor do maior, e pegarei os que estão acima do maior+maior*10%. No caso, o meu "topo" (a base do retângulo em vermelhor) será maior+maior*10%.